# Put output from system() into a text view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a terminal-like app, and using `system()` in my code. I want to put the output from that into a text view.  I can see some of its output in the `NSLog()` box in Xcode, but I can't figure this one out. If it's out there on Google I couldn't find it.

Comment: If you've got it printing in the console, you're probably about 95% of the way there. Can you show the code you're using to go from `system()` to `NSLog()`?

Comment: It's automatic.  When you use system() it automatically sends it to nslog... My question I guess is how to I display console data in a text view and I'm pretty sure that I would get a lot of shit for asking that lol

Comment: Yup, never mind; I forgot what system did. You need to read this Big Nerd Ranch blog post about hijacking stdout and redirecting it to a `UITextView`: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1836-hijacking-for-fun-and-profit/

Comment: Put that as an answer so I can give you points.

Comment: Glad I could help, but answers that are just links really aren't good. Please seriously consider coming back when you've got a working solution and posting some details as an answer yourself.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes you are absolutely right. But to help other you may put this in an answer with some context about it :)

Comment: I haven't got the energy to reread and summarize the article right now, @InderKumarRathore, and it'll be more helpful to everyone if evan shares his final solution anyways.

Comment: Now @evan.stoddard it's all on you to give an appropriate answer

Comment: Now I'm having build errors.... heres my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741652/i-keep-getting-an-arc-error-when-building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded source from because blog.bignerdranch.com/1836-hijacking-for-fun-and-profit.    You then call the functions that he declared which I'm pretty sure you guys know how to do.  But I will show you how I called the functions.

First you have to link the classes.  Then in the view did load method you have to start the high jacking.

```
    // Hijack standard out.
self.stdoutHijacker = [XXFdHijacker hijackerWithFd: fileno(stdout)];
setbuf (stdout, NULL);
self.stdoutHijacker.delegate = self;
[self.stdoutHijacker startHijacking];
[self.stdoutHijacker startReplicating];

// Hijack standard error
self.stderrHijacker = [XXFdHijacker hijackerWithFd: fileno(stderr)];
setbuf (stderr, NULL);
self.stderrHijacker.delegate = self;
[self.stderrHijacker startHijacking];
[self.stderrHijacker startReplicating];

self.contents = [NSMutableString string];
```

After that I had an IBAction for when a person typed in a command.  system() takes a const char so I had to convert the text in the text field to a const char so I will just show you system() with some text in it

```
-(IBAction)doCommand:(id)sender{
    system("ls");  //shows contents of root directory in my case
}
```

Next we define a void to scroll to end of text view

```
- (void) scrollToEnd {
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange (self.contents.length, 0);
    [self.loggingView scrollRangeToVisible: range];
} // scrollToEnd
```

Finally we get the text

```
- (void) hijacker: (XXFdHijacker *) hijacker  gotText: (NSString *) text {
    if (hijacker == self.stdoutHijacker) [self.contents appendString: @"stdout: "];
    if (hijacker == self.stderrHijacker) [self.contents appendString: @"stderr: "];

    [self.contents appendString: text];
    self.loggingView.text = self.contents;
    [self scrollToEnd];
} // hijacker
```

This will get both errors and an anything sent to NSLog.  If you don't want errors then erase

```
// Hijack standard error
self.stderrHijacker = [XXFdHijacker hijackerWithFd: fileno(stderr)];
setbuf (stderr, NULL);
self.stderrHijacker.delegate = self;
[self.stderrHijacker startHijacking];
[self.stderrHijacker startReplicating];
```

from viewDidLoad.  If you only want data then erase

```
    // Hijack standard out.
self.stdoutHijacker = [XXFdHijacker hijackerWithFd: fileno(stdout)];
setbuf (stdout, NULL);
self.stdoutHijacker.delegate = self;
[self.stdoutHijacker startHijacking];
[self.stdoutHijacker startReplicating];
```

Oh and one more thing...add the top of your implementation file of the view controller you will be using the code in.  Make it look exactly like mine except change where it says viewController to the name of your view controller

```
    @interface XXViewController () <XXFdHijackerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *loggingView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) XXFdHijacker *stdoutHijacker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) XXFdHijacker *stderrHijacker;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *contents;

@end // extension
```

Comment: No problem.  I had a problem the two files I got from the source where it wasn't linked with my project.  Make sure you do that haha.  I'm kind of a n00b so it was good that I learned it early on.